# ¿Cómo puedo invocar un método en otra clase? Java

Tags: java, poo

```java
package Examenlogin;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Menusito {
    public void main(String [] args){
        String  nombre;
        String contraseña;
        int opcion;
        int opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bienvenido a su login uwu"
            + "\n1. Login\n"
            + "\n2. Registrate\n"
            + "\n3. Salir\n"
        ));

        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                Login.primera = new login();
                primera.login();
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

El método que quiero invocar es este :

```java
package Examenlogin;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Login {
    public void primera(){
        int opcionn;

        opcionn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(""
            + "\n1. agregar\n"
            + "\n2. modificar\n"
            + "\n3. eliminar\n"
        ));

        switch(opcionn){
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: me refiero a unir, mandar a llamar un metodo

Comment: amigo sabes como eliminar un registro ?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, primero asegúrate que tenga el modificador de acceso (sin modificador, public, protected private) necesario para que puedas invocar ese método.

**Método 1:** Creando un objeto de la clase

```java
Login login = new Login();
login.primera();
```

**Método 2:** haciendo el método estático para no necesitar crear el objeto de la clase

```java
public class Login {

    public static void primera(){
       // ...
    }
}
```

```java
Login.primera();
```

Comment: A su vez, se podría reducir a `primera()` haciendo el import estatico: `import static com.ExampleLogin.Login.primera;`